# How to avoid that a Team is automically added to the Azure-DevOps Groups of a new repository

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working with an shared ADS test installation and every time when I create a new repository, it's automatically adding a Team (which is created by another person) to the Azure-DevOps Group.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this or is there a way to delete this from the groups in this repository?

[image]

[image]

Thanks for the help

Zlatan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to avoid that a Team is automically added to the Azure-DevOps Groups of a new repository

That because this group xxx team is added for your all Git repositories.

> Is there a way to avoid this or is there a way to delete this from the
> groups in this repository?

We could delete this from the groups for one specify repository. To enable the Remove button, you could try to change the inheritance from **On** to **Off**:

[image]

[image]

Then you could change the inheritance to **On**.

**Note:** Make sure you have permission to manage permissions for a repository, you must be a member of the **Project Administrators** group. Check this document [Set repository permissions for Git or TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you also know how to avoid that "xxx Team" is added automatically? Remove it from "Git repositories" and in future "xxx Team" is not added by default to a new repository?

Comment: @ge45mue, As I test, the answer is yes. But you should fully confirm that you no longer need it.

Comment: The 'xxx Team' is still required as a 'Team', but it should not appear as a default member in the 'Azure Devops Groups' field of any repository. As mentioned in the question, I'm working in a test system and it's no problem when I destroy something. So do you know how to completely remove it from "Git repositories"?

Comment: @ge45mue, Just like you delete it from one repo, click the Git repositories, and remove the team. If you are member of Project Administrators, the remove button still not enable?

Comment: @ge45mue, np, you are always welcome. Have a nice day!